# typeof is not able to return the datatype in LWC .js

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have used lwc data table and have set columns as below.

```
const columns = [
{label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', sortable: true},
{label: 'Active', fieldName: 'active', type: 'boolean', sortable: true}
];
```

then over a sort function I am getting the fieldName and tryoing to sort.

```
if(typeof fieldname === 'string'){
        data.sort((a,b) => {
            let valueA = key(a) ? key(a).toLowerCase() : '';
            let valueB = key(b) ? key(b).toLowerCase() : '';
            return reverse * ((valueA > valueB) - (valueB > valueA));
        });
    }else{
        data.sort(function(a,b){
            var a = key(a) ? key(a) : '';
            var b = key(b) ? key(b) : '';
            return reverse * ((a>b) - (b>a));
        });
    }
```

"**`if(typeof fieldname === 'string')`**" is always returning data type as string and not returning the Active field as boolean.

Basically I am trying to implement sort function where I am trying to sort text and checkbox values.

Comment: Note that js is a case-sensitive language. Thus `fieldName !== fieldname`

Comment: it worked like below by converting all boolean values into string:                           let valueA = key(a) ? key(a).toString().toLowerCase() : '';
let valueB = key(b) ? key(b).toString().toLowerCase() : '';

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` operator returns the evaluated type of variable passed in (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

In your case, you're passing in a value of `fieldName` which is, in truth, `string` for both your columns:

```
const columns = [
{label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', sortable: true},
{label: 'Active', fieldName: 'active', type: 'boolean', sortable: true}
];
```

```
typeof columns[0] /// 'string'
typeof columns[1] /// 'string'
```

What you meant to do was check if `columns[index].type` equals to your expected data, e.g. like so

```
// it is not clear where you get fieldName from, so might as well get type there, too
if(type === 'string'){ 
        // do whatever
    }else{
       // do whatever again
    }
```

Further, as you noted in your comments, your sorting methods are very close and can be merged like so:

```
function valueConverter(val) => val ? (typeof val === 'string' ? val : val.toString()).toLowerCase() : '';

  data.sort((a,b) => {
            let valueA = valueConverter(key(a));
            let valueB = valueConverter(key(b));
            return reverse * ((valueA > valueB) - (valueB > valueA));
        });
```